# Excel Macro Err 9 - Subscript Out of Range - Error on Run but not when stepping through (f8)

Tags: excel, vba, subscript

I have written a VBA code to step through a selection of hyperlinks and grab data from each file.

On the 2nd pass through the loop (when I run the macro), I get an err 9 - subscript out of range.  When I step through the macro via the F8 button, it runs fine.

I have done a debug while running and the Range(x.Address) has the correct cell address.
If I run the code for the line that fails as the first entry, it works.

It just fails on the 2nd run.

```
Sub HistoricRevData()

On Error GoTo MHSErrorHandler:

Dim WB_MonthlyLoad As Object
Dim WB_ProjectSummary As Object
Dim WS_MonthSht As Object
Dim WS_PerComSht As Object
Dim WS_PriceSht As Object
Dim WS_RevSht As Object
Dim varLastCol As Integer
Dim varRowCount As Integer

'save the MonthlyLoad book as an object for easy reference
Set WB_MonthlyLoad = ActiveWorkbook
Set WS_MonthSht = ActiveSheet
Set WS_PriceSht = WB_MonthlyLoad.Sheets("Price")
Set WS_RevSht = WB_MonthlyLoad.Sheets("Revenue")
varRowCount = 2

'Open the Project Summary Report and save as object
'  - Note right now this just does the single project need to loop through all
'
For Each x In Selection.Cells

    If x.Value <> "" Then
        Range(x.Address).Hyperlinks(1).Follow NewWindow:=False, AddHistory:=True
        Worksheets("% Complete").Select
        Set WB_ProjectSummary = ActiveWorkbook
        Set WS_PerComSht = WB_ProjectSummary.Worksheets("% Complete")
        WB_MonthlyLoad.Activate
        varLastCol = WS_PerComSht.Rows(5).Find(What:="Total", LookIn:=xlFormulas).Column - 2

        WS_PriceSht.Cells(varRowCount, 1).Value = WS_PerComSht.Cells(7, 1).Value
        WS_PerComSht.Range(WS_PerComSht.Cells(8, 4), WS_PerComSht.Cells(8, varLastCol)).Copy
        WS_PriceSht.Cells(varRowCount, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        WS_RevSht.Cells(varRowCount, 1).Value = WS_PerComSht.Cells(7, 1).Value
        WS_PerComSht.Range(WS_PerComSht.Cells(41, 4), WS_PerComSht.Cells(41, varLastCol)).Copy
        WS_RevSht.Cells(varRowCount, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

        varRowCount = varRowCount + 1
    End If

MHSDate:
    WB_ProjectSummary.Close savechanges:=False

MHSLink:
     Next x

Exit Sub

'==========================================================================================
MHSErrorHandler:

MsgBox (Err.Description & " - " & Err.Number & x.Address)

If Err.Description = "Cannot open the specified file." Then
    Err.Clear
    Resume MHSLink
End If

If Err.Number = 91 Then
        Err.Clear
        WS_MonthSht.Cells(x.Row, 6).Value = "On % Comp, Couldn't find Total Column"
        Resume MHSDate
End If

'===============================================================================================

End Sub
```

Anyone have any ideas

Comment: `Anyone have any ideas` Yup. Avoid `ActiveWorkbook/ActiveSheet/Selection` You may want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: I hate debugging these, but I've had it happen to me a few times - trying to remember how exactly I fixed the issue.... you might want to replace activeworkbook with thisworkbook, and consider changing activesheet to a sheet reference, if it's always the same sheet

Comment: When you debug, your `ThisWorkbook` becomes `ActiveWorkbook` as you are pressing `F8` which makes it active.  But when you are running the code, it is possible that it is picking up some other workbook as `ActiveWorkbook`. See the link that I posted above, Appropriately declare and set your objects and you should be fine.

Comment: Piggy-backing on Sid's point about appropriately declaring... `Range(x.Address)` versus `WS_MonthSht.Range(x.Address)` would do wonders for you, where `WS_MonthSht` has been set to a specific sheet by its name/index.

Comment: Thank you all - I will implement the above and report back.

Comment: changing the selection to a defined range fixed the problem.  Thanks all